# input type="file" is not opening the file browser from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm not sure if it's a bug or something simple that I just missed...
Here is a simple test case. The index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test file input field</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="file">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The manifest is calling it inside a popup:

```
"popup": "index.html"
```

I was expecting to get the 'file browser' after clicking the 'file' button but it is vanish after 0.5sec. 
(It's on Mac 10.6.8 and Chrome 14.0.835.186)

Any idea?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, logged at http://crbug.com/98920